# Cannot redirect when doing post request

Tags: node.js, express

I am using request module for doing post request. After the post request, I wish to redirect user. But it seems to me that i am unable to do redirect here.

```
function callApi(req, res) {
    request(options, function(err, response, body){
        res.redirect('/'); //cannot read property redirect of undefined, can't set headers after they are sent
    });
}

function callApi(req, res) {
    request(options, function(err, response, body){
        req.res.redirect('/'); // can't set headers after they are sent
    });
}
```

Comment: did you try making the status code res.statuscode = 301;??

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon what do you mean by that? I just try `req.redirect(301, '/')` and it still return the same result

Comment: res.statusCode='301'; res.redirect('/'); res.end(''); depending on the express version you are using less steps will work.  notice that in your code you use req.res. should only be res.

Answer (score 1):

Inside callback your res would refer the response from request callback. do this...

```
function callApi(request, response) {
request(options, function(req, res, body){
    response.redirect('/'); //cannot read property redirect of undefined, can't set headers after they are sent
   });
}

function callApi(request, response) {
   request(options, function(req, res, body){
      response.redirect('/'); // can't set headers after they are sent
   });
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code in this topic as i update wrongly. It should be `request(options, function(error, response, body)`. So i guess this is not the problem